# Sequential Divergence Criteria for Functional Limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing

Let $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and let c be a cluster point of A. Then prove that
$\lim_{x \rightarrow c}f(x)$ does not exist in $\mathbb{R}$ $\Rightarrow$ there exists a sequence $x_n$ in A, $x_n \neq c$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x_n)$ diverges
This was given as an if and only if statement in my analysis textbook. I have proved one side of the statement ie converse of the one mentioned above. But doing this one is actually futile. I am not even sure whether this is true. My attempt goes as follows:
Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow c}f(x) \neq a$ since lim f(x) does not exist. By a theorem mentioned in my textbook, there exists a sequence $x_n$ in A , $x_n \rightarrow c$ such that $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $a$.I am stuck at this point. I want to say since $a$ is arbitrary, $f(x_n)$ does not converge to any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ hence $f(x_n)$ diverges. But i realised that if i take any other, say $b \in \mathbb{R}$  it is not necessary that the same sequence $x_n$ will not converge to $b$. There could be any other sequence not equal to $x_n$ that the theorem in my textbook guarantees. Am i proceeding correctly or is there any other way i should go about, or is this statement false. Any hints would be appreciated.